# How to disable the on key press exiting

Tags: c++

I like to code and am trying a new language.  C++ is new to me but I have 1 question.  How do I change the fact that when I build and run my C++ console app it asks me to press any key to quit but I only want it to quit when I press the ESC key.  How do I disable the thing that makes me press any key to quit?  I am using Visual Studio 2022 with the C++ Console Application template.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void main () {

  char message[21] = "Hello There!";
  cout << message;

  if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
  {
      exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: the "press any key " message is put there by vs2022 *after* your program has finished, so you can see the output

Comment: `if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))` isn't in a loop so it happens once, and whether the key has been pressed or not your program exits because there isn't anything after that to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `GetAsyncKeyState()` returns immediately. You are asking it to see if the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key is *currently* pressed. It returns 0 or 1, then the code carries on, so you exit from `main()` any way. What you want is this:

```
void main() {

    char message[21] = "Hello There!";
    cout << message;

    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
    {
        Sleep(500);

    }
}
```

Comment: When I enter that it gives me the error "identifier "Sleep" is undefined"

Comment: @ChefMe727 you need `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: @ChefMe727 cmon, you can work out how to make that work if you can find GetASyncKeyState

Comment: @pm100 "*It returns 0 or 1*" - incorrect, the return value of [`GetAsyncKeyState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) is not a boolean: "*If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the key is currently up or down. If the **most significant bit** is set, the key is down, and if the **least significant bit** is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau you're a hard task master :-)

Comment: This is an answer which may be found by future googling. Hence, it should be correct (instead of showing a correct code with an incorrect explanation). With a score of 36k (Respect!), you actually should've known...